# Laravel is caching my code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I recently changed from CodeIgniter to Laravel. I love the way it works, but I only have one problem. When I make a mistake (which because laravel is new to me, it is often) I want change the problem. When I refresh the page to test it out again the same error comes up again. Even when the code is deleted that gives the error.

When I put on debug mode I can see the code line where there is a problem. When I change the code I can see that in the exception (because it shows some of the code where the error is) and even there it is gone, but not the error.

Is it possible to disable this on development mode? I can't find some solutions, but I don't know how to google for it.

You guys know this?

### Edit

Here you have some coding examples. If I do something stupid like:

```
Router::action('HomeController@getIndex');
```

It gives me the error: Class Router doesn't have the method action(). And that's true, it's a mistake that I made because I mess up the names between Router and Redirect (because it's all a bit new for me).

When I change this to:

```
Redirect::action('HomeController@getIndex');
```

It's the code that works, just from the documentation of laravel, but laravel or the browser still gives me the Router doesn't have action() error, even when I changed it or even deleted it.

I hope this gives you more explenation about my problem :)

Comment: How sure are you that the error is the same one for the same piece of code?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it's the same error, that's because the debug gives the same error.

Comment: Would help to actually see some of your code and the errors.

Comment: @treeface I have edited the question with some sample code. It's as simple as that, so I don't know if you need some more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finnaly found out what the problem was with my caching.
It wasn't Laravel that cached my results, but it was PHP 5.5.3 on MAMP.

It turns out that PHP 5.5.3 on MAMP has OPCache on with the default settings.

Guys, I really appreciate your help! And I hope I can help you out someday.

Comment: I've also ran into MAMP caching problems before, but then I created a virtual machine for development, which is a lot safer to your system and you can even use it on an external drive so you can carry it with you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond. I've already found out what the problem was. It wasn't any header, or PHP related configuration in the scripts or so. It was the OPcache that was introduced in the new MAMP version. I turn it off and it worked again.

Comment: I noticed, I was just sharing my experience with it and advising people to use virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default cache on laravel. Maybe the cache of your web-browser?

Comment: Do you know how to prevent the browser from caching? The header thingy doesnt work.

Comment: Depends on your browser, in Chrome you can toggle it in the web inspector settings (ctrl+shift+i then click on the gear)

Answer (score -1):

Varnish seems to respect modified headers.
You could try this in php:

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate');
header('Expires: Tue, 04 Sep 2012 05:32:29 GMT');
```

source:
http://blog.jambura.com/2013/09/04/disable-varnish-cache-using-http-headers/

Answer (score -2):

Is there and compiled.php in the /bootstrap/ dir?

Comment: No there isn't any compiled.php in the bootstrap folder

Comment: Ok, the final thing I can think of is a cache on the webserver. My current host (pcextreme) works with a Varnish cache which tends to delay changes on files. (even force refresh doesn't always work)