# Apache is apointing to a wrong git branch

Tags: git, apache, github

I have a code on folder www in wamp localhost server and versioned on git. 
but when i switch the selected branch, the IDE reflect this but the web site doesnt show the correct branch. (before worked)

How can i solve this?

here, the correct branch selected:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? You are changing branches on an IDE and your terminal doesn't reflect this? .. I don't understand.

Comment: I'm changing a branch on terminal. The IDE reflect this, but when I run the web site, is running other branch.

Comment: Any cache in place for your webpages?

Comment: I tried CTRL + F5 one milion times

Comment: Are you using any framework or CMS? I'm asking this because some of them can store information in cache (in databases). Some days ago I was working with Drupal and every time I changed an entity I needed to run the command drupal update:entities, otherwise, Drupal would keep my old code.

Comment: @RicardoMontuan based on the tiny bit of code we can see I would bet on a Laravel app

Comment: @Paulo If you're using opcache maybe your scripts are being loaded from memory. I suggest you to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19504912/10933257).

Comment: @RicardoMontuan i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

To switch between git branch you need to use `git checkout "your branch name"` command.

The git branch commands primary functions are to create, list, rename and delete branches. To operate further on the resulting branches the command is commonly used with other commands like git checkout